# how does the question "can I talk to my duck at work" meet the site's guidelines?

Tags: discussion

A few of my questions have been closed in the past because "a question by definition has an answer", and so on.

However, by looking at questions with the most votes, I can see this recent example:

"[Can I talk to my rubber duck at work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83451/can-i-talk-to-my-rubber-duck-at-work)"

Now, in the real world the professionality of talking to a rubber duck would depend a lot from company culture. I assume it would be very different at a Big4 or in a startup.

This question is closely related to a specific work environment.
And its chosen answer is even spectacularly generic, "in the IT world it's generally accepted".

In the past I asked questions about "is this part of startup life" or "can I expect this from a  startup", and my questions were closed with the usual motivation of "questions by definition have an answer".

In comparison to that glorious example, why would "in startups this is what generally happens" be unacceptable, as opposed to closing a question?

I am baffled.

Comment: Oh, I remember that one. In case it makes you feel any better, the question *was* closed but then some people decided it would be a good idea to reopen it, so it was reopened. You can check that in the edit history if you are interested.

Comment: It seems that very popular questions can get away with things.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a long history on that question's [timeline](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/83451/timeline)... but I get where you're coming from.

Stack Exchange is a "self moderated democracy" and it only takes 5 votes to close (or re-open) a question, which out of this site's 35,000 users (active in the last year) means only 0.01% have to *"like or dislike"* your question in order for it to thrive or be closed.

Overall it's a good system, but it's not perfect, especially since humans aren't perfect.  Much like a workplace, **popularity** definitely impacts question scores, even though it shouldn't (in *either* situation).

I'd suggest that the next time you post, add more information to your post - and perhaps try wording it in such a way that people can **relate to** the topic will generate more interest.  I don't have a lot of experience on *this* site but I've seen this technique makes a difference on Stack Overflow, where only 0.0001% of users need to "dislike" a question for it to be closed (which I've seen happen within seconds of being asked).

Perhaps you can get some ideas from this site's lists of:

- [**Top questions by votes**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)
- [**Top questions by views**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A250)

(At first glance, the "most popular" questions *seem* reasonable.)

---

Does it make you feel any better that ***this question*** is a "Hot Post"?!

[image: hot post]